# Cordova Add build date AND OR git version to a popup triggered by a button in app

Tags: git, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on a Ionic project which requires commit id/version from Git and the build date accessible from a button triggered popup in the app. I've already tried [Cordova app version plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-appversion) but it does not suit my requirements, it only shows the version number from `config.xml` whereas I want the build date and the Git version. What are my options?

Answer (score -1):

When you are using a git repository services like github or bitbucket e.g. you can use their APIs to get information about your version / commit, the dates and many more. See [github API get](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get) or [Bitbucket API get](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html).

If you are using your private repository services, as far as I can imagine you would have to write your own API that gives you the git version / build date.